# using enumerator between class and object

Tags: c#, struct, foreach, enumerator

I have an array of struct in an object. I want to pass each of these struct in the array to the class using a foreach loop so that I can display each struct in the class.
Here is the code in the object to pass the struct :

```
public IEnumerator recup_voitures()
{
    foreach (voiture v in _arrVCollection)
    {
        yield return (v);
    }
}
```

and I try to reccuperate these in the class using :

```
foreach (CarCollection.voiture o in collection.recup_voitures())
{
   //some console.writeline to display whats inside each struct 
}
```

this dosen't work. I get an error that say that it dosen't have a public GetEnumerator.
Can anyone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return an IEnumer**able**.  (preferably `IEnumerable<T>`)

`foreach` operates on (objects that look like) `IEnumerable<T>` and calls `GetEnumerator()` to enumerate over the collection.

Comment: i'm sorry but I don't see what you mean I allready declare my function as returning an IEnumerator

Comment: It should be `IEnumerable<voiture>` or `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerator`.